# HIbernate query parameter binding

Tags: hibernate

I would like to perform native SQL query via hibernate:

```
dbs.createSQLQuery("UPDATE USERS SET :balanceType = :newBalance WHERE UKEY = :ukey")
    .setString("balanceType", type.toString())
    .setBigDecimal("newBalance", newBalance)
    .setLong("ukey", uKey).executeUpdate();
```

This fails because of :balanceType binding.

I get the exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

org.hibernate.exception.NestableDelegate@431d9f05
could not execute native bulk manipulation query
UPDATE USERS SET :balanceType = :newBalance WHERE UKEY = :ukey
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

If I use String.format to embed paraneters in string then it works fine!

Any idea what's wrong with my syntax??

Thanks!

Comment: `balanceType` is not a parameter, you cannot bind it

Comment: what is retuned by `type.toString()`?

Answer (score 0):

`balanceType` is not a parameter, so you cannot bind it, you need to concatenate the column name using string concatenation.

```
dbs.createSQLQuery("UPDATE USERS SET " + type.toString() + " = :newBalance WHERE UKEY = :ukey")
    .setBigDecimal("newBalance", newBalance)
    .setLong("ukey", uKey).executeUpdate();
```